# Cant seem to find how to check for valid emails in App Engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

any one know where any docs might be about this?
So far I've only found this

http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/djangoforms.html

EmailProperty() only validates for empty strings... *sigh*

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? If you are just looking for docs - http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#emailfield

Comment: There are no docs for it, because App Engine doesn't include any email validation components.  Validating that an email is valid without sending a message to it is far from trivial.

Comment: Well I came up with a a solution http://angelmedrano.com/?p=207

Comment: ah, you weren't looking to validate that an email actually works, you just wanted to know if a string had an @ sign in it and looked like an email string.

Comment: Peter, I suppose you are correct. I'll take any built in method that will does some sort of validation. Do you know a better solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following validates the email address on the server:

```
from google.appengine.api import mail
if not mail.is_email_valid(to_addr):
  # Return an error message...
```

Hope that helps?

Comment: I wonder if thats a newer feature. I couldn't find anything like that when a few months back. Thanks!

Comment: Simply does not work, mail.is_email_valid('asd') returns false. Looking at the source, this method does little but check that the string isn't blank

Comment: [Proof](https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/57258/763708/zsiLwRtwx1om9II/upload.png)

Comment: @pheelicks I think you meant `mail.is_email_valid('asd')` returns `true`

Answer (score 3):

If you check the source for Google's [mail](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/api/mail.py?spec=svn257&r=257#212) function you'll see  that **mail.is_email_valid()** only checks that the string is not None/empty.

From this [site](http://iamcal.com/publish/articles/php/parsing_email/) I found an [RFC822](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/rfc/822addr.html) compliant Python email address validator.

```
import re

qtext = '[^\\x0d\\x22\\x5c\\x80-\\xff]'
dtext = '[^\\x0d\\x5b-\\x5d\\x80-\\xff]'
atom = '[^\\x00-\\x20\\x22\\x28\\x29\\x2c\\x2e\\x3a-\\x3c\\x3e\\x40\\x5b-\\x5d\\x7f-\\xff]+'
quoted_pair = '\\x5c[\\x00-\\x7f]'
domain_literal = "\\x5b(?:%s|%s)*\\x5d" % (dtext, quoted_pair)
quoted_string = "\\x22(?:%s|%s)*\\x22" % (qtext, quoted_pair)
domain_ref = atom
sub_domain = "(?:%s|%s)" % (domain_ref, domain_literal)
word = "(?:%s|%s)" % (atom, quoted_string)
domain = "%s(?:\\x2e%s)*" % (sub_domain, sub_domain)
local_part = "%s(?:\\x2e%s)*" % (word, word)
addr_spec = "%s\\x40%s" % (local_part, domain)


email_address = re.compile('\A%s\Z' % addr_spec)
# How this is used: 
def isValidEmailAddress(email):
    if email_address.match(email):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

* If you use this please use [this](http://tfletcher.com/lib/rfc822.py) version as it contains the name and so on of the person whom created it.